# I need help for create Excel Pivot

Tags: c#, excel, exception, interop

I want to export my datatable with interop to excel.
I have 4 columns, 11 row DataTable.

This is my full function, where the datatable should be exported:

```
static string ExportExcelInterop(DataTable Report, JToken fields)
    {
        string fileName = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\ExcelRapor.xlsx";
        var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var workBook = app.Workbooks.Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
        var sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.ActiveSheet;
        for (var i = 0; i < Report.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < Report.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                sheet.Cells[1, j + 1] = Report.Columns[j].ColumnName;
                sheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = Report.Rows[i][j];
            }
        }
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange = sheet.Range["A$1:D$11"];
        if (app.Application.Sheets.Count < 2)
        {
            sheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.Add();
        }
        else
        {
            sheet = app.Worksheets[2];
        }
        sheet.Name = "Pivot Table";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRange2 = sheet.Cells[1, 1];
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache oPivotCache = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotCache)workBook.PivotCaches().Add(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotTableSourceType.xlDatabase, oRange);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable oPivotTable = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotTable)sheet.PivotTables().Add(PivotCache: oPivotCache, TableDestination: oRange2, TableName: "Pivot Grid");
        
        foreach (var Columns in fields)
        {
            string dataField = null;
            string area = null;
            string areaIndex = null;
            string filterValues = null;
            string filterType = null;
            foreach (var Key in Columns)
            {
                string KeyName = Key.ToString().Substring(0, Key.ToString().IndexOf(':')).Substring(1, Key.ToString().Substring(1, Key.ToString().IndexOf(':')).Length - 2);
               
                foreach (var Value in Key)
                {
                    switch (KeyName)
                    {
                        case "dataField":
                            dataField = Value.ToString();
                            break;
                        case "area":
                            area = Value.ToString();
                            break;
                        case "areaIndex":
                            areaIndex = Value.ToString();
                            break;
                        case "filterValues":
                            filterValues = Value.ToString();
                            break;
                        case "filterType":
                            filterType = Value.ToString();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField oPivotField = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField)oPivotTable.PivotFields(dataField);
            if (area != null)
            {

                if (area == "row")
                {
                    oPivotField.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlRowField;
                }
                else if (area == "column")
                {
                    oPivotField.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlColumnField;
                }
                else if (area == "data")
                {
                    oPivotField.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlDataField;
                }
            }
        }

        workBook.SaveAs(fileName);
        workBook.Close(); 
        app.Quit(); 
        return fileName;
    }
```

I get Exception on 3th return foreach.
My exception:
`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'PivotTable sınıfının PivotFields yöntemi başarısız'`
This error message translates to

```
PivotFields method of PivotTable class fails
```

I think I can't set correct `sheet.Range` so my pivot does not fit. But how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you verify if my translation of the Turkish error message is correct?

Comment: @CasperDijkstra yes its true thanks.